# Not able to access Redis remote server and cant read or write to redis database

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, redis

I'm trying to do accessing remote redis serverinto local server using node js, but it not showing any error or any success messages on logs with this code, I don't know what happening with this code, Can any one please help me to resolve it. Great Thank you in advance.

Getting this error while running the server 
Redis error: Error: Redis connection to 34.214.160.143:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT 34.214.160.143:6379

```
This is code im trying to access redis remote server database.
```

This is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var partials = require('express-partials');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var redis = require('redis');
var config = require('./config');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', { defaultLayout: 'layout' });

app.use(partials());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(cookieParser(config.secret));

console.log(config.redisConf);

var redisClient = redis.createClient(config.redisConf);

redisClient.on('connect', function (err) {
console.log('hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii11111111111111111');
if (err) {
console.log("Error " + err);
} else {
console.log('connected to redis!!');
}
});

redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
console.log('hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii222222222222222222');
if (err) {
console.log("Error " + err);
}
});

redisClient.set('framework', 'AngularJS', function (err, reply) {
if (err) {
console.log('terrror -- ' + err);
} else {
console.log('the framwork var was SET to AngularJS : the following is the server answer : ');
console.log(reply);
}
});

redisClient.get('framework', function (err, reply) {
if (err) {
console.log('terrror -- ' + err);
} else {
console.log('result' + reply);
}
});

app.use(session({
secret: config.secret,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient })

}));

// right after the session
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(config.port);
console.log("App server running on port " + config.port);

and this is config.js file

var config = {
port: 3000,
secret: 'secret',

redisConf: {
host: '34.214.160.143', // The redis's server ip 
port: '6379',
pass : 'foobared'
}
};

module.exports = config;
```

But its not showing any results or error messages on logs
Can any one please help me to resolve this one, Great thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to check the firewall settings on the server the redis server is located on. I tried to connect to your redis server from my ubuntu using:

> redis-cli -h 34.214.160.14 -p 6379 -a foobared

and got:

Could not connect to Redis at 34.214.160.14:6379: Connection timed out

Assuming the redis server is up & running - it might be related to the firewall.

Comment: How to check firewall settings on ubuntu, Actually it is an another nginx server and on that server i installed redis and its setup.

Comment: Check firewall settings using sudo ufw status  and its showing as 
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
4000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
4000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: You need to check firewall rules on the server the redis is installed on. You need to allows TCP connections for the port 6379 - this is the port the redis server is listening.
Also please make sure the redis service on that server is up & running.

Comment: do yo have ssh access on the server that hosts redis? if so, here is another answered questions that showed how to do the settings for redis: https://serverfault.com/questions/715659/how-can-i-add-rule-to-iptables-on-ubuntu-to-enable-redis-on-local-ip-but-not-ext

Comment: Thank you very much @Marian Dinu, we will try it the TCP connections and settings for redis on server.